# How do you save a global variable in swift once app has closed?

Tags: swift, variables, save, global, exit

I have created a global variable in "view controller 1" which appears properly across my 3 different view controllers.
I am incrementing this global variable in "view controller 2" and presenting the result also in "view controller 3". This is all functioning properly.

My issue is that when I close the app, my global variable resets to the originally assigned value. This is some of the code in "view controller 1":

```
var globalScore = 1

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

And this some code in "view controller 2":

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(globalScore, forKey: "savedLevel")
```

Can someone please give a basic example of how to save global variables even once app is closed?

Thanks

Comment: How do you use this global variable ?

Comment: I am creating a quiz game and the global variable is a score integer. This integer increments by 1 each time an answer is answered correctly. When the user is to enter the app again after closing it, they should still begin on the same question number (i.e. score is still the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
var globalScore:Int { 
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey:"savedLevel")
    }
    set {
     UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "savedLevel")
   }
 }
```

Comment: I have edited my original Q, I declare my global score in "view controller 1" but I am setting it to a new value in "view controller 2". How can I make use of your code for this? Or is there a different way I should structure my code? Any comments would be appreciated. Thanks